# adjust audio ballance in android programmatically

Tags: android

```
mMemoryStorage.musicSrv.getPlayer().setVolume(leftVolume, volume);
```

I'm using this method to control volume in my app but when I tried to implement method that helps to adjust volume ballance it didn't work out. 
(leftVolume parameter differs from volume parameter, they are both float). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does your device have stereo sound?

Comment: i'm using android studio emulator. how to check it?

Comment: use some player that already has this feature implemented. I think that the emulator just has mono sound

Comment: ok thanks) so does this method work?

Comment: it should work, but might not. That's what you can check by yourself. I personally newer used it to balance channels, so I can't tell you if it works, but on the other hand - I don't know a method which exists in Android SDK for long time, and does not work. So if it was not working, it was either removed, or fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!)))